# Help finding the transfer matrix for this system

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

Find the transfer function of the following system:
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{x}_1&=&ax_1+bx_2 + u\\
\dot{x}_2 &=&-bx_1 +ax_2\\
\dot{x}_3&=&cx_3\\
y &=& x_1+x_3
\end{eqnarray}
Now I am given the formula for the transfer matrix as $T(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B+D$. Here the 4 matrices are
$$A =  \left(\begin{matrix}   a & b&0\\-b&a&0\\ 0&0 & c  \end{matrix} \right)$$
$$B =  \left(\begin{matrix}    1\\0\\0 \end{matrix} \right)$$
$$C =  \left(\begin{matrix}1&0&1     \end{matrix} \right)$$
$$D =  \left(\begin{matrix}   0  \end{matrix} \right)$$.
Now the transfer matrix I am looking for is thus given as:
$$T(s) = \left(\begin{matrix}1&0&1     \end{matrix} \right) \left(\begin{matrix}  s- a & -b&0\\b&s-a&0\\ 0&0 & s-c  \end{matrix} \right)^{-1} \left(\begin{matrix}    1\\0\\1 \end{matrix} \right)$$
Now I am stuck on finding $\left(\begin{matrix}  s- a & -b&0\\b&s-a&0\\ 0&0 & s-c  \end{matrix} \right)^{-1}$. Can anyone help with this? Or did I make a mistake earlier on? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Your $B$ matrix is wrong. $u$ appears only once. The matrix inversion should be straightforward, it is basically a 2x2 inversion.

Comment: As sorry I see my mistake in the $B$ matrix. Thanks for the spot.

Comment: I am also confused about $x_3'$. Is that correct? In other words, it is not part of $A$ as written.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the really sloppy work... You are right it's not correct. Will update and thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

First note that $x_3$ is uncontrollable, and so will not contribute to the transfer function. (Another way to see this is to note that the transfer function gives the zero-state response to an input $u$, and we see that $x_3(t) = 0$ whenever the initial state is zero.) Hence $\hat{x_3} = 0$.

You have $s \hat{x_1}(s) = a \hat{x_1}(s) + b \hat{x_2}(s) + \hat{u}(s)$, $s \hat{x_2}(s) = a \hat{x_2}(s) - b \hat{x_1}(s)$. Solving for $\hat{x_1}$ (that is, eliminating $\hat{x_2}$) gives
$\hat{x_1}(s) = \frac{s-a}{(s-a)^2+b^2} \hat{u}(s)$. Since $\hat{y} = \hat{x_1}+ \hat{x_3}$, we have
$$\hat{h}(s) = \frac{s-a}{(s-a)^2+b^2}$$